# Springboot: difference between responsibilities of dependencies grouped as STARTER vs CORE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependencies, microservices

In springboot applications, various dependencies are injected, in a project.

These dependenices generally, categoriesed as *STARTER or CORE or DATA*

I understand that, those grouped under **data**, refer to libraries interacting with repository/database

*The differnece between responsibilities of **starter** and **core** is not clear.*

Taking instances, whats difference in responsibilities of

- spring-cloud-starter-sleuth vs spring-cloud-sleuth-core
- spring-data-redis vs  spring-data-redis-core

So what additional is featured, when some dependency appends **core** to it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `starter` dependencies content.

`Starters` are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application.

Their provide a quick way to configure our application, without manually including a lot of related dependencies.

`Core` library contains the code: classes, methods, functions...